# Power BI Empty Visualization Fix

Tags: powerbi

Wondering if anyone has been able to find a good way to use some kind of placeholder when the visualization in Power BI shows empty.

This usually happens after filtering and receiving no data for some metrics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit dirty, but sometimes I just make a measure, which checks for blanks in another measure. ISBLANK -> "No Data", otherwise: "" (empty string). Put this measure in a Card, and place it over the visual.

```
IfBlankMeasure = IF(ISBLANK([Measure]);"No Data!";"")
```

Without data:

[image: Without Data]

With data:

[image: With Data]